# Highlight Text after ng-view location Change in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to highlight some text using this [jquery highlight plugin](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html) after a user changes the ng-view location; The text to be highlighted is on the returned page.

On success of the view change, I run the `highlight()` method:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
    console.log('success');
    $("p").highlight(["text"]);
});
```

My success log is printed, however the text never highlights.

My files are loaded correctly because I can run the action on my browser console and my defined text gets highlighted, so I'm not sure what's wrong here. Any ideas?

Thanks much!

Comment: You can use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) to build a angular directive or service and don't forget to include a CSS style for the highlighted element.

Answer (score 1):

When writing Angular code, It's generally discouraged to manipulate the DOM directly, as one would typically do with jQuery. Instead, you should use Angular's logical attributes to create the appearance of a changing DOM. While I can't understand why your particular example doesn't work, an alternative and more "Angular" solution could be something like this:

```
<p ng-style="{'background-color': highlight}"></p>
```

And then in your JS file, you'd set the value of highlight

```
if bla
  $scope.highlight = '#FFFF88';
else
  $scope.highlight = '#FFFFFF';
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip @nmg49! I'll still need to traverse the DOM however to find the text I need to highlight, not focused on so much on the method of highlighting yet

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this only by using Angular's `$timeout` and creating a timeout method

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
    console.log('success');
    $timeout(callTimeout, 1);
});
...
function callTimeout(){
    $("p").highlight(["text", "text2", "text3"]);
}
```

I'm not sure why yet, but it would not work without this. I'll update this answer if I find the solid reason

Thanks